# Is there a polyfill for window.DOMParser() for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, domparser

I am trying to recreate the xml to json converted based on DOMParser. Is there a way to make it work for NodeJS

Comment: Have you checked out the already existing packages that do this sort of thing in npmjs?

Comment: I am looking for an equivalent of x2js at git. But none is close to it

Comment: Unable to find equivalent of https://github.com/abdmob/x2js/

Comment: How about [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/x2js) or [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-x2js)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/x2js is fine thanks. But I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom which is exactly what Domparser does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact polyfill for Domparser in node is xmldom package at https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom